# Apex class using App Cloud

Tags: apex, appcloud

I want to develop a custom app on force.com platform using apex code only. I don't want to use any sales or service cloud. Which edition should I buy. I have a plan to send email to my customers.
Can anyone help me out to find a solution. Open to any suggestion.

Comment: Your question is way too broad. Can you be more specific with your needs?

Answer (score 0):

you can start with building the app in developer account. Once its completed and you know what all standard functionality you need for your app to be functioning properly.you can buy receptive org according to that and deploy your app there by packaging.
Hope its help.